# Precision loss reading from `r16Snorm` texture to `half` variable in Metal

Tags: ios, floating-point, precision, metal, half-precision-float

Am I correct in my assumption that reading a value from `.r16SNorm` texture into Metal Shading Language `half` data type always unavoidably incur precision loss? It wasn't obvious to me from the start because they both 16-bit formats. But I guess `.r16SNorm` can store much more precise values in its interval [-1, 1] at the expense of dropping any values outside of this interval. Basically if I understand correctly `UNorm` and `SNorm` formats don't have any exponent bits and use all 16-bits for significand and sign exclusively thus dramatic difference in precision compared to `half`.

Does it mean that its almost never makes sense to read from `r16SNorm` to anything other then `float`? Or maybe there is a way to "renormalize" is somehow?

```
// texture is in .r16SNorm pixel format
texture2d<half, access::sample> texture [[texture(0)]] 

...

// float is fine
float value = texture.sample(sampler, pixel).x;

// half is never enough to store normalized 16-bit???
half value = texture.sample(sampler, pixel).x;
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question. But to elaborate. `half` is a 16-bit IEEE 754 floating-point number. `SNorm` format on a contrary is just an integer that represents a fixed point number. It's normalized at sampling time by dividing it by the max value and shifting it, basically. If you compare ulps, the half can't fit the 16-bit snorm value.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the hardware is going to sample the values in full 32 bit floats anyway and then it will "put" it in either 32 bit "variable" or into a 16-bit variable. So the only thing you are saving here by using float is registers and ALU. So it's a tradeoff. And no, there's no way to "renormalize" it. The half you would get with the second `sample` is normalized, it's just not as precise.

Comment: Thank you for clarifications! Did you mean "saving here by using **half**"?

Comment: What makes you think that hardware would always sample the values in full 32 bit floats anyway? Does something imply that Apple GPUs have only 32 bit texture/sampling bus width? Does this in turn mean that there is never performance difference between using`texture2d<half>` vs `texture2d<float>`?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but in this exact case, there's no way to normalize the 16-bit snorm without doing the math in 32 bit floating point, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: But the difference between `texture2d<float, ...>` and `texture2d<half, ...>` would be something that you can measure with a microbenchmark.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes sense, I didn't think of it. However if you use `texture2d<half>` you kind of agreed to precision loss, so why not use `half` to normalize snorm internally as well.

Comment: Well the compiler that’s gonna emit the instructions for the hardware does not know which texture formats are actually gonna be in the texture, so I don’t think it actually can do that. I might be wrong.